# Encoding elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing

Given the following list of numbers:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 8, 9, 10, 10, 2]
```

The objective is to obtain a numeric representation of an array when all that matters is identifying distinct values.

```
indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 1]
```

I tried to solve it with the following function:

```
def first_occurrences(L):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if i not in result:
            result.append(i)
        else:
            result.append(L.index(i))
    return result
```

which gives me a wrong output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I thought about using a dictionary, but I don't know how it should be done

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can first build a dictionary with element-index pairs:

```
lookup = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(dict.fromkeys(mylist))}
# {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 8: 4, 9: 5, 10: 6}
```

And then use this dictionary to lookup indices:

```
[lookup[i] for i in mylist]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 1]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

see below

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 8, 9, 10, 10, 2]
seen = dict()
for idx, x in enumerate(mylist):
    if x not in seen:
        seen[x] = idx
newList = [seen[x] for x in mylist]
print(newList)
```

output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1]
```

Comment: @alex108 Lets look at the first index of 10 - it is 8. do we agree on that ? In the other answer and in your question it is 6. Can you please explain why?